# solving LP problem : no optimal solution exists?

Tags: optimization, simplex

$$\max[Z(x,y)=3x+2y]$$

$$-x+y\le 1$$

$$-x+2y\le4$$

When I tried to solve the above maximization LP problem using the simplex method, from the first iteration, all basic variables became negative.

When I searched for an online tool to solve this LP problem, I found that no optimal solution exists.

How can I know that my LP problem has no optimal solution so that I can stop iterations?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You need both $\;y\le 1+x\;,\;\;y\le\frac12x+2\;$ , and this zone isn't bounded to the right of the origin. It's clear the problem as no maximum as you can take for example $\;(x,0)\,,\,\,x>>0\;$ and the value of $\;z(x,0)\;$ will increase unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x \geq 0$, set $y=\frac{x}{2}$, so that $-x + y = -\frac{x}{2} \leq 0 \leq 1$ and $-x + 2y =  0 \leq 4$. The constraints are satisfied, and the objective value is $$3x + 2y = 4x \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} +\infty$$
i.e. the objective is unbounded.